# How to tell which key called a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

If I have an object with multiple keys calling the same function and this function is implemented outside its scope, how to determine which key called this function? For example:

```
function tellYourAge() {
   return function()
   {
       // I already know here that this refers to Population
       // For example, console.log(this) will print the Population object
   }
}

{
   let Population = {
     Mahdi: tellYourAge(),
     Samuel: tellYourAge(),
     Jon: tellYourAge()
   };

   Population.Mahdi(); // It should log 18
   Population.Samuel(); // It should log 20
   Population.Jon(); // It should log 21
}
```

Comment: not possible to know that info.

Comment: Pass the key as a parameter like: `Mahdi: tellYourAge('Mahdi')`

Comment: I want to do it without passing a parameter

Comment: Those are already separate functions.

Comment: `I want to do it without passing a parameter ` why?

Comment: Where is the age stored? This seems like it should be a method on the individual's objects.

Comment: There is no link from the key to the value. You either have to pass it or you have to rethink how it is being set up.

Comment: The age is not stored because its a simple example with three names only.

Comment: You cannot achieve this exactly in the manner described. You might be able to do something either with block scoping or Function.prototype.bind.

Comment: can you further explain

Comment: Why do you want to write the code this way? What benefit do you think it has? The person who inherits this code (if you find a way to write it this way) is not going to understand what you are doing especially if you use some hack like grepping a stack trace string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible

```
function tellYourAge() {
   return function()
   {
       var f = arguments.callee;
       var key = Object.keys(this).filter(key => this[key] === f)[0];
       console.log(key);
   }
}

{
   let Population = {
     Mahdi: tellYourAge(),
     Samuel: tellYourAge(),
     Jon: tellYourAge()
   };

   Population.Mahdi(); // prints Mahdi
   Population.Samuel(); // prints Samuel
   Population.Jon(); // prints Jon
}
```

Explanation: `arguments.callee` is reference to the function to which the `arguments` object belongs. And `this` is basically "a thing before the dot" at the moment of function invocation, therefore your `Population` object. Now what you do is lookup the called function instance in the object and you are done.

Comment: good hint! some considerations for callee: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: I recommend using [`.find(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `.filter(...)[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function tellYourAge() {
   return function()
   {
      var s = new Error().stack;
      if(s.includes('Mahdi')){
        console.log('Age is 18');
      }

      else if(s.includes('Samuel')){
        console.log('Age is 20');
      }

      else if(s.includes('Jon')){
        console.log('Age is 21');
      } 
   }
}

{
   let Population = {
     Mahdi: tellYourAge(),
     Samuel: tellYourAge(),
     Jon: tellYourAge()
   };

   Population.Mahdi(); // It should log 18
   Population.Samuel(); // It should log 20
   Population.Jon(); // It should log 21
}
```

```
Output:
Age is 18
Age is 20
Age is 21
```

FYI, new Error().stack will give you stacktrace like below,

```
Error
    at Object.Samuel (<anonymous>:4:20)
    at <anonymous>:1:19
```

Comment: how does this answer my question?

Comment: Check my updated code. I think we can figure out the key only from the stack trace.

Comment: @MahdiJaber ... from the example you gave and the requirements of not wanting to provide any argument to any function in any form ... this is exactly what you will get as sole approach that meets all those requirements.

Comment: Hopefully OP doesn't actually do this, but I'm upvoting because it's a legitimate answer. I've done stack-inspecting code too, under duress. I guess what's particularly egregious here is A: It's part of the main program flow, not a logger or an error handler. B: It's creating an Error. (is there a way to ask for the stack without an error?) and C: it's parsing the stack as a string, which is clearly error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question to be how can I associate a person's age with their name.  The way I would do it is to create objects which describe people.  Each object would have two attributes, a name and an age.

The objects (people) would then be stored in an array which is the population.

```js
// Create a constructor function which defines a Person
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

// Create an array of Population to store the Persons (people)
var Population = [];
Population.push(new Person('Mahdi', 18));
Population.push(new Person('Samuel', 20));
Population.push(new Person('John', 21));

// Counter and limit variables
var i, l;

// Loop through the Population and display the information about the people
l = Population.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  let person = Population[i];
  console.log(person.name + " is " + person.age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained *why* you don't want to "pass a parameter", or what *exactly* the requirement to not pass a parameter is. My guess is that you want to keep the returned integer (or other value) dynamic in some sense specific to your context.

Here's how I might suggest doing it, although it's still not clear if it's a good idea:

```
function tellYourAge() {
  return function(name)
  {
    let ages = {
      Mahdi: 18,
      Samuel: 20,
      Jon: 21,
    };
    return ages[name];
  }
}

{
  let makePopulation = function(names){
    let pop = {};
    names.forEach(function(n){
      pop[n] = tellYourAge().bind(pop, n);
    });
    return pop;
  };

  let Population = makePopulation("Mahdi", "Samuel", "Jon");

  Population.Mahdi(); // It should log 18
  Population.Samuel(); // It should log 20
  Population.Jon(); // It should log 21
}
```

Comment: The introduction of the new function `makePopulation` is just stylistic. I don't like to see a variable mutated, like how `pop` is above. Sometimes it's necessary when setting up the value in question; in those cases I like to wrap up the mutation/initialization so it can be considered outside of the rest of the program flow.